# What are the (dis)advantages of holding two positions at different institutions?

Tags: career-path, affiliation

Multiple affiliations are not uncommon in academia but often the second/*n*th affiliation is in name only. My question is about double affiliation where a person has active employment in both institutions to some degree (e.g., 70-90% at Institution A and 30-10% at Institution B). What are advantages/disadvantages of such arrangements?

---

(My hypothetical situation involves positions in different fields at Institutions A and B (both in EU but different countries) that have a positive view of such arrangement, but I would be very interested in reading answers of a more general setting, too.)

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps your situation is different, but when I've encountered people with these sorts of "split" appointments, it isn't as if they were weighing as options two alternatives: full appointment at A, or split appointment at B+C (where A could be the same as B or C) and considering the advantages/disadvantages of a split appointment. Rather, the split was *solving some problem* or *fulfilling some otherwise unachievable goal*. The advantage, therefore, is that it solved the problem; any disadvantages are secondary to the problem that is solved, and are mostly issues of convenience.

To give some examples from people I've worked with (and some of these circumstances are quite common and apply to multiple people):

- The primary salary is paid by a hospital or similar clinical organization, and is a clinical-only role. Research is performed under a separate appointment with a university. There are no other options to do both clinical work and research at those institutions.
- A separate appointment is required to have access to some particular facilities important for research such as medical imaging equipment, clinical staff, or data. The latter is particularly relevant for large, institutionally supported research studies where there is no realistic alternative to do the same work somewhere else.
- Someone has a grant for a multi-year project, and is hired to a new position elsewhere they would like to take. The only way to maintain their previous grant and comply with institution/grant agency guidelines is to keep a partial appointment at the old institution, possibly in another country.
- A dual appointment is necessary to supervise graduate students in the other program/department/institution. This may be similar to the previous example, where an appointment is maintained in order to complete supervision for some students at a previous institution, or it may be forward-looking, especially for separate appointments within the same institution.

In these circumstances, there may certainly be an institution that acts as the "primary" one, but I would dispute the "in name only" characterization: even the non-primary institution is an important association that is necessary for all or a substantial portion of the researcher's work.

For your case, I'd ask myself: what goal are you trying to solve? Is solving that goal worth the additional administrative demands on your time, keeping two "bosses" happy, possible conflicts of interest, etc? I think the specific disadvantages are too situation-specific to name. It's likely if the goal is sufficiently important, none of that other stuff will matter in comparison. If it's unimportant or a mere matter of convenience, all the extra inconvenience will add up quickly.

Comment: Upvote for the idea that such arrangements typically arise as solutions to a problem. However, the arrangement might still provide additional benefits beyond solving the problem, and consequently become more long-term after the original problem has been solved.

Comment: Very good points but - to me - this answer is more about the "why" and not the (dis)advantages.

Comment: @Aolon I think the disadvantages are too dependent on the particular situation; they are not general features of holding two positions. The advantages are primarily that they solve some problem, such as the examples I give. I don't think it's really possible to separate "why"s from "advantages" - the most important advantages are the "why" in making a decision.

Comment: I am sorry but I disagree, the other replies mention quite a few such as tax issues, handling grants and affiliations, dealing with the bureaucracy of two departments, etc. Actually, you also mention a few in your last paragraph such as conflicts of interest.

Answer (score 5):

Advantages:

- **Potentially higher salary.** In Europe, it's generally possible to hold more than 100% worth of positions at one time (e.g., 100% at institution A and 20% at institution B would be fairly common). In such an arrangement, one advantage would be higher overall salary.
- **Being able to apply for grants in two countries.** Being affiliated in several countries can give access to more funding opportunities. That's especially the case as funding agencies often limit the number of grants that one can apply for at one time.
- **Being able to supervise students at all levels in two institutions.** Students from the two institutions might have complementary skill sets and could be used interchangeably for projects (e.g., sending students from A to B for their thesis projects).
- **More networking and collaboration opportunities.** Typically, both institutions would expect that you spend some amount of time there in person (for the downside of that, see below). Spending time at your home institution naturally leads to interactions, which could strengthen one's network and lead to collaborations.

Disadvantages:

- **Travel overhead.** Typically, both institutions would expect that you spend some amount of time there in person. Two issues with that: First, traveling and accommodation may be expensive (but the institutions might be willing to cover that). Second, traveling may have a non-monetary cost (harder to maintain a satisfying personal life as one is "living in two countries").
- **Being a frequently absent supervisor.** Supervised team members (Ph.D. students, post-docs) at the "second" institution need to arrange themselves with having a frequently absent supervisor. While regular online supervision meetings can make up for that to some extent, some students clearly prefer a present supervisor, especially at the beginning of a Ph.D. project or post-doc, where there might be more need for guidance and informally bonding with the supervisor (e.g, having lunch together).

Comment: I think this is the most useful answer, though each answer has something great. This one is missing tax issues (Scott Seidman), potential conflicts of interest (Bryan Krause), bureaucracy of two departments and affiliations (EarlGrey).

Answer (score 2):

Towards other people, one possible disadvantage is the order of the affiliation is important, in papers' affiliation one may think that the current affiliation is the last one.

In general, one writes "now at" to explicitly state that ... but people unfortunately make a lot of assumptions.

Regarding private matters, if the funding is coming from both institutions, the overhead due to bureaucracy regarding holidays, HR matters, IT accounts and so on can rapidly grow to being from an annoyance to unbereable.

Therefore, I would suggest you to find a way to be employed by only institution A, while B pays your salary (+ overhead) to institution A. This way you keep the affiliation with B (it must be explicitly written in the agreement), while reducing your bureaucracy load.

I assume A is a laboratory and B is an university: the biggest advantage is you can get "access" to students from institution B. Otherwise, unless you have academic goals (i.e. becoming a professor), being employed by an university and at a laboratory is a pain in the neck: you have no additional advantage/stability from
being a researcher at the uni, but you have additional duties.

Comment: Interesting, I have never put any thought to the order of affiliations, certainly not with regard to chronology (I would list my current affiliation first?). I have also never seen in my fields a "now at" note.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not a full-time employee in the US, there might be benefits issues involving things like health insurance, retirement contributions, tuition benefits, ....

Earning in two countries may also involve tax considerations.

Comment: The stated 70-90% should be more than enough to triggle benefits at most US schools.  But this is certainly something to look out for.

Comment: Good catch. I forgot about the benefits. Medical is a big item here. In Europe it might be or not, though social insurance is generally much better there. I don't know how it works for partial contracts, but in Germany, self employed people pay a lot of taxes but don't get all the benefits (older information - may be obsolete).

Comment: Good point about the benefits and also about the potential issues in the US. I think in many European countries, benefits depend on the % of employment (e.g., employees get some benefits only if they are employed x% or more).

Comment: @Aolon, this all means you need to know these issues before signing on the dotted line, unless you're In a situation where you can roll with whatever the answers are.

Comment: Completely agreed and I have scheduled appointments with HR and the Tax Office to discuss the options. I am just hoping that all the experience of SE contributors might help me catch potential drawbacks I did not think of.