What are the pros and cons of keeping a casual contract with an old university?
I'm moving cities, as I have accepted a job offer at a new university. My old research group is asking me to keep a casual contract with them, so that if they need my assistance with any of the technical aspects of their projects (which was my role), I can help out.
I've heard that many academics keep a small portion of casual FTE with multiple universities. What are the pros and cons of this approach versus making a clean break and starting afresh elsewhere?
Here's my list so far. Pros of keeping casual contract:

I'll be involved in more publications from the old university, which could improve my academic standing
I'll keep ties with that university in case I ever want to go back

Cons:

I'll have less time to focus on projects and teaching at the new university if I keep up work for the old university
If I want to preserve energy, I'll have to keep saying 'no' to old projects, which is hard

Any other thoughts?
Thanks a lot

I think the pros and cons will depend strongly on the terms of the contract. What are they offering and what do they expect in return?

I think the biggest issues will be non-academic in nature. E.g. regulations about side jobs, minimum/maximum percentages, sick and holiday leave, tax-issues, having to do bureaucracy in a place you no longer live in, funding/affiliation/acknowledgement issues, etc.

Can you define "casual contract"? Does it involve money? Are there "contractual obligations"? Or is it just a form of interpersonal relationship and research process?

https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/187082/63475 may also be related.

Check your new university's rules about outside consulting. I've seen rules like "Consulting jobs outside the university are allowed for up to 8 hours per week, as long as they don't detract from your university work." I imagine these rules vary widely between universities.
